# Нет, нам нужно спрятать книгу - мало ли, что нас ожидает

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

1) Нет, нам нужно спрятать книгу - мало ли, что нас ожидает. 
2) Боже, сколько же крови ты потеряла, - надо обработать рану. 
Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложениях?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) ***Нет, нам нужно спрятать книгу — мало ли что нас ожидает.***

2) ***Боже, сколько же крови ты потеряла — надо обработать рану.***

Тире обозначает причинно-следственные отношения между частями в бессоюзном сложном предложении (БСП).

***Мало ли что*** — устойчивое выражение, нет запятой перед ЧТО.

В предложении 2 не нужна запятая между простыми предложениями, так как там нет оборота, который надо закрывать. ***Боже*** — междометие.

Comment: Sharon , спасибо вам огромное... Мне так совестно: вы уже в прошлый раз объясняли такого рода предложение. Скажете, что никак не научусь. Но не думайте так, объяснение ваше я запомнила. Просто думала, что в данном втором предложении есть оборот, который надо закрыть. Спасибо, что разъяснили...

Comment: И Вам спасибо за  вопрос, мне было интересно отвечать.